# Vim syntax group not stopping

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

I recently upgraded to vim 8.2.0100 on Mac, and the markdown highlighting appears to have changed to be buggy.

Here is an example:

```
Normal syntax *Highlighting has started* Highlight continues
Highlight continues...
```

meaning the second `*` does not stop the highlighting on italics.

I see that `echo &filetype` returns `markdown`, and that `:scriptnames` includes (among many other files) `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.2.0100/share/vim/vim82/syntax/markdown.vim`

In the markdown syntax file, I see:

```
" start matches a non-whitespace character if preceeded by a * OR a * followed by a non-whitespace character.
" end   matches a non-whitespace character if preceeded by a * OR a * followed by a non-whitespace character
exe 'syn region markdownItalic matchgroup=markdownItalicDelimiter start="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" end="\S\@<=\*\|\*\S\@=" skip="\\*" contains=markdownLineStart,@Spell' . s:concealends
```

The comments are my own attempt to understand the syntax.

I have tried changing it a bunch, including just setting `start="ic"` and `end="xc"`, but that **doesn't work**; I have the same problem where the start turns on the highlighting, but the end fails to turn it off.

This happens **even with `vim <filename> -u NONE`** (after I set the filetype to markdown and turn on syntax), meaning my `.vimrc` is not related

What am I missing in how to edit syntax files, or why doesn't the `end` get any matches?

Edit: I have noticed that it also does not work with **Bold** (`**Bold**`), and the bold will continue on through the rest of the document. Other segments, notably ```` ``` ````, do stop their changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's just broke in 8.2.0100.

Here's the committed fix: https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/commit/e875717243fbea38189f5590a25a05809f03672b

The problem was with the `skip="\\*"`. It was supposed to match the literal characters `\*`, so that you could display a literal `*` in markdown. However, `\\` makes a literal `\`, so he was instead skipping any amount of `\` characters, which included 0 backslash characters, which meant "skip everything". `\\\*` instead matches a literal `\*`, which is what you should write to display a literal `*` in your markdown output.

TL;DR: Change all instances of `skip="\\*"` in `markdown.vim` to `skip="\\\*"` and everything works.

Comment: Yah, I emailed Tim Pope about it when I noticed. It should make it to the next upstream release.